# I may need to reinstall Ubuntu on USB drive

Tags: 16.04, usb, reinstall

I have installed Ubuntu on a USB drive, however lately the system has been running poorly. Often the screen turns grayish and everthing hangs for a while. This occurs most often using Firefox, but it occurs at other times as well. Is there an easy way to reinstall Ubuntu on the same USB?

I have:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Intel® Core™ i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8
- 15.6 GiB Memory
- 105.3 GB available on USB disk
- 2 - USB 3.0
- 2 - USB 2.0

Comment: Most probably the way you did it the first time?

Comment: Sounds like a slow USB 2 drive, try a faster one or a USB 3 drive.